# How do I eval the code when run its test in elisp with Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm writing some small puzzles to learn Emacs Lisp.

However, my current workflow is way too tedious :

1. change the code
2. `eval-region` or `eval-buffer` code
3. change the test
4. `eval-region` or `eval-buffer` test code
5. `M-x ert`, then press enter to run tests

How do I setup Emacs or the tests, so I can just "run the test" and Emacs will eval all codes for me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should not run your tests within your Emacs session anyway.  Rather, run the tests in a fresh Emacs session:

```
$ emacs -Q -b -l my-source-file.el -l my-test-file.el -f ert-run-tests-batch-and-exit
```

You can run this from `M-x compile`.

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty much what I need. But I have to replace `-b` with `-batch`

Comment: Do you think the test itself should require the code under test? That seems to be how I do things in other languages.

Comment: @jplindstrom I think so, and I usually have a corresponding `require` in place.  It lets you byte-compile the test code cleanly, and thus helps you to find mistakes (e.g. misspelled functions or variables, etc.), especially with [Flycheck](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck) (shameless plug :) )