# Executing LISP programs in GNU Emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp, sicp

I've been learning to use the GNU Emacs lately and have developed quite an interest in using the same as my text editor to replace text editors in my Linux Mint Olivia. I've also been watching MIT videos on Structural Interpretation of Computer Programs and am interested try my hand at LISP to solve problems like the ones that are there at project Euler.
I have tried a lot to search on the internet for how to write and execute LISP programs in Emacs, some like the ones that are shown in MIT lectures. I've tried the 'lisp-mode', 'lisp-interaction-mode', etc. but no luck.

Any help would be higly appreciated.

Comment: use `SLIME` to execute programs in an external Lisp process through an Emacs buffer.

Comment: SICP is in Scheme, which is indeed a kind of Lisp but fairly different from Emacs Lisp or Common Lisp. Make sure the solution you find supports Scheme specifically.

Comment: I've tried http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/ and it works fine just that it is a separate software altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally settled with MIT-Scheme (http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme).
One can do all the exercises shown in SICP lectures there.

OR

You could use `lisp-interaction-mode` in Emacs, and move thru evaluating statements.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for REPL way, you can use `M-x ielm`, which is a built-in Emacs Lisp REPL

If you want to just compile the lisp file and execute the code, you can check [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450737/how-do-i-eval-the-code-when-run-its-test-in-elisp-with-emacs) I asked recently.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the [Quack mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/QuackMode) for emacs (the counterpart of DrRacket) for doing HtDP/SICP stuff.  It's worked and been prettier than the DrRacket GUI.

Comment: I downloaded Quack, created my '.macs' file and loaded the plugin. The Quack menu now shows up on the emacs menubar. Now when I select to run scheme, it asks me about scheme buffer, etc. Any pointers?

Comment: Hmmm... not from personal experience.  I use emacs only through the terminal.  What specifically does it ask?

Comment: It asks me for what scheme to run it with (default: mzscheme). In later attempts it says, "No process current buffer. Set 'scheme-buffer' or execute 'run-scheme' ".

Comment: It doesn't use Emacs for the Lisp, it wants an external Scheme interpreter to interact with.